# Best practices for passing events in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, events, event-handling

I'm curious how other developers deal with situations where events can be coming from different source elements and are being passed down to other elements.

The example below is generally what I'm talking about. The `.parent` element is passing an event it receives down to `.child`, which can also end up passing that same event down to `.grandchild`. At the same time, `.child` subscribes to events as well, and those events could also be passed down to `.grandchild`.

In my example, I basically have helper functions that take in an event as a parameter (`updateChildren` and `updateGrandchildren`). But I can see this problem being solved numerous ways. The event could be baked into the data object that gets associated with an element in D3 through the `.data` method. A `d3.local` variable could also be used.

But I see tradeoffs to each approach depending on the circumstances. And it also depends on whether the code is written in a single file or multiple. If I had placed `updateChildren` and `updateGrandchildren` into separate files, it gets trickier using `d3.local` to pass around events.

Just looking to get other people's perspectives on this problem. I can see this becoming quite hairy in large codebases, and I'm sure the use of the name `event` gets confusing when events could be coming from different source elements.

Note: I didn't test out this code, so it's possible it doesn't even run. It's just meant to demonstrate a situation where events are coming from different elements and are being passed down to other elements.

```
const data = [{someProperty: 'dummyData'}]
const parentSelection = d3.selectAll('.parent')
  .data(data)
  .join(enter => enter.append('div').classed('parent', true))
  .on('someEvent', function (event) { 
    updateChildren(d3.select(this), event)
  })
  .on('someOtherEvent', function (event) {
    updateChildren(d3.select(this), event)
  })

updateChildren(parentSelection, null)

function updateChildren (s, event) {
  const childSelection = s.selectAll('.child')
    .data(d => [d])
    .join(enter => enter.append('div').classed('child', true))
    .on('click', function (event) {
      updateGrandchildren(d3.select(this), event)
    })
    .each(function () {
      if (event.type === 'someOtherEvent') {
        // Do something following 'someOtherEvent'
      }
    })
    
  updateGrandchildren(childSelection, event)    
}

function updateGrandchildren(s, event) {
    s.selectAll('.grandchild')
    .data(d => [d])
    .join(enter => enter.append('div').classed('grandchild', true))
    .each(function () {
      if (event.type === 'someEvent') {
        // Do something following 'someEvent'
      } else if (event.type === 'click') {
        // Do something following 'click'
      } else  {
        // Do something else
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: First of all, your code won't work: you cannot use `d3.selectAll` with `data`. Also, your grandchild is just a child (have a look at where you are appending it). Thus, as you said yourself, please test the code beforehand, so you can see that it at least runs.

Comment: But the most important is this: your goal is far from clear. Why are you passing the event if the only thing your function (`updateChildren`, and also `updateGrandChildren`) is doing is joining elements based on (the same) data? Finally, the event is an object, so what's exactly the comparison you're doing on the if condition? Do you mean `event.type`?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Those are some good catches. I went ahead and revised my code based on your comments. But again, I'm just trying to get other developers' perspectives on best practices for passing around events. I didn't mean to limit the conversation specifically to the example I wrote.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado What do you mean by you cannot use `d3.selectAll` with `data`? As far as I know, the two can be used together.

Comment: You can't. Just try it and you'll see, no element will be appended anywhere.

Comment: Regarding your question about best practices, what I'd do (and most of d3 codes we see around) is using `d3.dispatch` to dispatch the event, no need for messing with the `event` object like you did here.